# How can i display pdf or docx file from xsl-fo?

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, docx

My task is this,

If the user attaches a file(image or pdf or docx(word 2007 format))

it saves it in the DB.

-> succeded this module.

After that, if the user press save button, it has to save it to a pdf file.

I googled how to display images

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block text-align="center">
                        <fo:external-graphic src="C:\Users\spark\Desktop\ui.png" />
                    </fo:block>

                </fo:flow>

</fo:page-sequence>
```

but i don't have any clue how to display other formats...pdf and docx...

Can you suggest me a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache FOP has an extension that may be helpful which adds the `<fox:external-document>` tag which supports embedding PDFs. Documents can be embedded at the page-sequence level.

```
<fo:page-sequence ...>
...
</fo:page-sequence>
<fox:external-document src="C:\Path\to\PDF\myDoc.pdf" />
...
```

[Apache's Documentation](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/extensions.html#external-document)

[Author's Documentation](http://www.jeremias-maerki.ch/development/fop/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i read the docs and follow the sample codes, but it has these error and not displaying :( Trying to figure it out.                             SEVERE: Image not available. URI: C:\Users\spark\Downloads\sample.pdf. Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for C:\Users\spark\Downloads\sample.pdf (No context info available)